# Iterating through list of JDO objects with Google Cloud SQL extremely slow

Tags: google-cloud-sql, jdo, datanucleus

I have a Google Cloud SQL db with about 100 items in it - when I query it with JDO (using datanucleus plugin) and try to print each item it takes about 30 seconds to iterate through the list.  I put some trace on there and every iteration through the loop takes about 300-1200ms.  This only seems to happen when the cache is empty - subsequent calls to the same endpoint only takes about 300ms total to return all 100 items.  Running the query manually on the DB is very fast.  Could it be trying to fetch each object from the DB individually? Is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: Can you see the raw query/queries executed? Sometimes when ORMs misbehave they issue multiple queries when a single one would suffice (called "n+1 select" issue). Are the application and database located close by (same region/zone)?

Comment: I can't see the raw queries - is there a setting to enable debugging?  Yes the database is in the same region as the application.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with DataNucleaus. Most ORMs have an option to log the raw queries that are sent to the DB.

Comment: Most ORMs have documentation, like this one here http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/logging.html

Comment: I figured it out after I turned on logging - I wasn't iterating through the list from within a transaction so each iteration was creating a new connection to the db.  Don't understand why Datanucleus requires that...

Comment: Maybe it isn't DataNucleus that requires whatever you refer to, maybe its the JDO spec. But unless you present some actual code and facts then its hard to offer any input

Comment: @fitznd You should consider posting this comment as an answer to your question so it doesn't stay unanswered.